# Boost regex basic regular expression "+" repeat is not working

Tags: c++, regex, boost

I am trying to find if a regular expression is found in a string, I use the `regex::basic` because this is the only way I can use back reference with grouping is (,)
Here is the code I use:

```
std::string orig("abc.bc");
std::string::const_iterator start, end;
start = orig.begin();
end = orig.end();
boost::match_results<std::string::const_iterator> what;
regex reg("\([a-z]+\)\.\1", boost::regex::basic);
bool found = regex_search(start, end,  what, reg, boost::match_posix);
```

found will be false but it should be true,
when I have checked a used `regex("[a-z]", boost::regex::basic)` it returned true while using `regex("[a-z]+", boost::regex::basic)` will return false.

Any Help with that?

Comment: yes, I the standard of the search says so

Comment: You are right it is like sed syntax.

Comment: Do note that `\(` is not a normal regex character. You need to escape the backslash or use a raw string literal for the regex to have a backslash.

Comment: According to the [documentation for basic POSIX regexes](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_55_0/libs/regex/doc/html/boost_regex/syntax/basic_syntax.html), there is no +. You might wish to try extended or something like Perl's.

Comment: Your string doesn't contain any parenthesis, hence the match failure. You've escaped them, so they're not treated as capturing, but instead are actually looking for parenthesis.

Since you appear to want to use them as a capture, try `"([a-z]+)\.\1"`

Comment: @DaveS, POSIX needs them to be escaped.

Comment: Ok, try with `"\\([a-z]\\{1,\\}\\)\\.\\1"`.

Comment: I have tried using regex::emacs and it worked will, so I think this was the answer

Comment: Or maybe more legibly, with `R"#(\([a-z]\{1,\}\)\.\1)#"`